# how to write to a file, from coq

Tags: coq

This is probably a strange question to ask since Coq is supposed to be a purely functional language, but `Extraction` exists and it clearly has side effects, so I'd assume there's probably a more basic command to just output a string or some constant to a file, something like this:

```
Extraction "file.txt" "hello"%string.
```

Is this possible? Would it require writing a custom extractor (I don't even know if that's possible) ?

The practical reason for this question is related to the motivation for the extraction mechanism that is already present in Coq, but let's say I want to output C code or something else that's not currently supported. I could still write a function in Coq `extract : Expr -> string` for a custom syntax that I formalize in an inductive type `Expr`. How can I get this string out to a file?

Comment: Extraction to Haskell and OCaml is defined as [a plugin](https://github.com/coq/coq/tree/master/plugins/extraction) so you could probably define your own extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Redirect` with `Eval` to get close:

```
Require Import String.
Open Scope string_scope.

Redirect "file.txt" Eval compute in "hello".

(* file.txt.out now contains:
     = "hello"
     : string
*)
```

Alternately, write your function `extract` in Coq, then use the extraction mechanism to extract `extract e` for some `e` of interest, and finally write an OCaml program that imports this (string) constant and prints it. The reason to go this route is that building up strings in Coq is so slow that you might not be able to run `Eval compute extract e` but you might be able to run it in OCaml. You can also then (in an unverified manner) replace Coq strings with OCaml native strings so this process is actually efficient; this is easy to do by importing `ExtrOcamlString` in Coq before extraction.